# error message of calling media translation api of GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi, machine-translation

I followed the tutorial in the
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/tutorials/ar-subs/index.md
to create Real-Time Video Translation with AR Subtitles.

After following all steps correctly, when I attempt to call the media translation API by typing in

```
python3 translate-microphone.py --lang it-IT --dev 0
```

but that doesn't work at all and the error message as follows:

Press any key to translate or 'q' to quit:
Begin speaking...

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/community/tutorials/ar-subs/translate-microphone.py", line 198, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/community/tutorials/ar-subs/translate-microphone.py", line 194, in main
    do_translation_loop(args.dev, args.lang)
  File "/home/pi/community/tutorials/ar-subs/translate-microphone.py", line 175, in do_translation_loop
    responses = client.streaming_translate_speech(requests)
  File "/home/pi/community/tutorials/ar-subs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/mediatranslation_v1beta1/services/speech_translation_service/client.py", line 467, in streaming_translate_speech
    response = rpc(requests, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/home/pi/community/tutorials/ar-subs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/community/tutorials/ar-subs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 156, in error_remapped_callable
    return _StreamingResponseIterator(
  File "/home/pi/community/tutorials/ar-subs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 82, in __init__
    self._stored_first_result = next(self._wrapped)
  File "/home/pi/community/tutorials/ar-subs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 426, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/home/pi/community/tutorials/ar-subs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 817, in _next
    _common.wait(self._state.condition.wait, _response_ready)
  File "/home/pi/community/tutorials/ar-subs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_common.py", line 141, in wait
    _wait_once(wait_fn, MAXIMUM_WAIT_TIMEOUT, spin_cb)
  File "/home/pi/community/tutorials/ar-subs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_common.py", line 106, in _wait_once
    wait_fn(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 316, in wait
    gotit = waiter.acquire(True, timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I googled that for a few days but got nothing.

Comment: Did you confirm that your microphone device number is 0?
Did you test it with the python3 mic_test.py --dev 0' command to be sure it is working. Because from your stack trace, it looks like the script is not getting the audio input and hits the maximum wait timeout.

Comment: Hi Ksign, thanks for your help and I confirm the device number is correct but it still doesn't work... in "Begin speaking" mode but no matter what I said nothing pops up and if I ctrl+C  the same error message.